# Windows Task Scheduler won't run powershell.exe

Tags: windows-10, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

I'm a security engineer with a background in Linux administration trying to teach myself about GPOs on evaluation copies of Windows Server 2016 Preview 5 and Windows 10 Enterprise. I created an immediate task to run a PowerShell script.

When the task tries to Execute, I get this warning in Event Viewer:

> Task Scheduler service found a misconfiguration in the NT TASK\EMET
>   5.51 definition. Additional Data: Error Value: powershell.exe.

Everything I've read suggests that this should be working. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the task in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScheduledTasks clsid="{CC63F200-7309-4ba0-B154-A71CD118DBCC}">
    <ImmediateTaskV2 clsid="{9756B581-76EC-4169-9AFC-0CA8D43ADB5F}" name="EMET 5.51" image="0" userContext="0" removePolicy="0" changed="2016-08-14 19:45:32" uid="{1CA5AB58-B38C-4F73-944F-9CDCBBF57037}">
        <Properties action="C" name="EMET 5.51" runAs="BYTHEBIT\Administrator" logonType="InteractiveToken">
            <Task version="1.2">
                <RegistrationInfo>
                    <Author>BYTHEBIT\Administrator</Author>
                    <Description></Description>
                </RegistrationInfo>
                <Principals>
                    <Principal id="Author">
                        <UserId>BYTHEBIT\Administrator</UserId>
                        <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
                        <RunLevel>HighestPrivilege</RunLevel>
                    </Principal>
                </Principals>
                <Settings>
                    <IdleSettings>
                        <Duration>PT5M</Duration>
                        <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
                        <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
                        <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
                    </IdleSettings>
                    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
                    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
                    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
                    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
                    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
                    <AllowStartOnDemand>false</AllowStartOnDemand>
                    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
                    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
                    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
                    <Priority>7</Priority>
                    <DeleteExpiredTaskAfter>PT0S</DeleteExpiredTaskAfter>
                </Settings>
                <Actions Context="Author">
                    <Exec>
                        <Command>powershell.exe</Command>
                        <Arguments>-NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\DC\Shared\Deployment\deployment.ps1</Arguments>
                    </Exec>
                </Actions>
                <Triggers>
                    <TimeTrigger>
                        <StartBoundary>%LocalTimeXmlEx%</StartBoundary>
                        <EndBoundary>%LocalTimeXmlEx%</EndBoundary>
                        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                    </TimeTrigger>
                </Triggers>
            </Task>
        </Properties>
        <Filters><FilterRunOnce hidden="1" not="0" bool="AND" id="{C58ADBD5-837B-46E8-98E4-80703D52F20E}"/>
        </Filters>
    </ImmediateTaskV2>
</ScheduledTasks>
```

Comment: Point the Task Scheduler to **"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"** explicitly and see what happens...this would be in the `<Command>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Command>` value part of the XML file rather than just the value of `powershell.exe` Let me know if this helps you any.

Comment: Additionally the `\\uncpath` to the PowerShell script may not be accessible from the local account your running this job as, try pointing it to a local server/PC drive letter path and ensure the script is saved there. Or run as a domain account with execute access to the UNC path where the PS script is saved rather than a running it as a local account.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look over my suggestions in the comments to see if those would resolve your issue?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Sorry for the very late reply, I did try both of those, and they also did not work. Although a few times nothing showed up in the event log (possibly from editing an event I marked as run-once?), so I could be doing something else wrong.

Comment: So rather that putting the `-NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\DC\Shared\Deployment\deployment.ps1` as the argument in your Task, just delete all that from the argument and then put `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "\\DC\Shared\Deployment\deployment.ps1"` as the command and see if you get different result so everything will be in the command and double quotes around the unc path of the PS1 file and no argument in Task Scheduler.